# What's the best .NET game development framework?

Tags: .net

I have dabbled in the Microsoft XNA game development framework which seems quite good and just wondered if anyone has had any experience with the [Dark GDK.NET](http://gdk.thegamecreators.com/?f=dgdk_net) from The Game Creators, or any others for that matter.

Any advice on which to get started with would be great.

Comment: Can you give more info about the type of game you're looking to build?  2d/3d? simple/complex, what style? windows/web/console?

Comment: Looking to build Windows PC based first of all starting with 2D then 3D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say stick to XNA.
It integrates well with VS, it has great community support, and you can also develop for the Xbox and the community games program.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). It supports three scripting languages:

- JavaScript
- C#
- [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) (a dialect of Python)

All the game logic runs on the open Source .NET platform [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page). Your game will work on a Mac, Windows, Wii, or even an iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

XNA without a doubt.  It has loads of abstractions around a lot of the painful lower level  stuff other SDK's force you to deal with.  And of course, VS & Xbox integration and the huge community help too!

Answer (score 1):

For 3D games I'd suggest XNA (although it lacks support for fixed function pipelines, you'll have to write all shaders yourself.)

For 2D games, [SDL.NET](http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) is a good choice, as it's comparatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try out http://www.neoaxis.com/ , it has impressive demos there, ready to be customized.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the lack of Windows 8 love that XNA is getting (support being dropped, apps won't be sellable on the app store) -- I'd go with SlimDX -- it's better than XNA anyway -- the only down side is that you can't make Xbox apps with it.